# Unable to use ByteArray value received

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, spyne, soapserver

I'm developing a soap web server with spyne.
I've defined the following method inside a Service class:

```
@rpc(String, String, String, String, String, DateTime, String, String,
         String, Integer32, ByteArray, _returns=ResponseCode)
    def add_ticket(ctx, t_id, text, cat1, cat2, cat3, date, user, service, attachment1_name, attachment1_size, attachment1_data):
        logging.info(f"Received ticket: {t_id} with category {cat1}/{cat2}/{cat3} under service {service}")

        logging.info(f"Attachment 1: {attachment1_data}")
```

Anyway I'm sending some simple pdf file encoded in base64 in the ByteArray field, but I'm receiving a tuple.
Is there a way to mantain or even re-encode in base64 what is received?

For example, I'm sending something that start with:

```
JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48/TDQoNCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZw0KL091dGxpb[...]
```

and receiving something that starts with:

```
(b'%PDF-1.4\n%\xc3\xa4\xc3\xbc\xc3\xb6\xc3\x9f\n2 0 obj\n<</Length 3 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>\nstream\nx\x9c\xad\x1aM\x8b[...]
```

I've read the answer in this stack overflow question: [python spyne service - base64 strings come escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356357/python-spyne-service-base64-strings-come-escaped) but it doesn't resolve my problem. I'm not able to define the deserialization method for ByteArray.

The option 2 in the answer is not the best that I can implement because in my wsdl file to share there would be

```
<xs:element name="attachment1_data" type="tns:add_ticket_attachment1_dataType" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
```

that is not a feasible data type name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ByteArray is used to abstract away binary encoding differences in different protocols. That's why you get a sequence of `bytes` objects, as documented [here](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/reference/model/binary.html#spyne.model.binary.ByteArray).

If you want the base64 string, just use the Unicode type.

If you want the base64 string yet you NEED to use ByteArray, you can try using `ByteArray(encoding=None)`, or subclassing the protocol and overriding the [`byte_array_from_element` function](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/4ae0653e1e426e8c2ee4e3044bb85d5b48c8c10b/spyne/protocol/xml.py#L1149)

Comment: Thank you @burak-arslan for the answer!
Unfortunately I need to replicate a wsdl where the field is reported as base64Binary, so I resolved the problem using the File data type, more specifically the 'data' field of File and it works. 
Do you see any problem doing this?

Comment: See my edit --b